# average of first, second...nth elements of a nested list

Tags: r

I have a nested list of p=100 elements containing q=50 items . I want to do average of all first elements, then average of all second elements and average of all third elements and so on. For example p=2 and q=3. The result that I need is a list or dataframe that contains averages of elements of `lll [[1]][[1]]` and`[[2]] [[1]]`, then `[[1]] [[2]]` and `[[2]][[2]]` , then `[[1]][[3]]` and `[[2]] [[3]]` which will be `(1+1)/2 ,(2+2)/2 = (1,2)`, `(3+3)/2,(4+4)/2=(3,4)` and `(5+5)/2,(6+6)/2=(5,6)`.

```
    l1<-as.matrix(c(1,2))
    l2<-as.matrix(c(3,4))
    l3<-as.matrix(c(5,6))
    l4<-as.matrix(c(1,2))
    l5<-as.matrix(c(3,4))
    l6<-as.matrix(c(5,6))
    ll1<-list(l1,l2,l3)
    ll2<-list(l4,l5,l6)
    lll<-list(ll1,ll2)

      lll
 [[1]]
 [[1]][[1]]
      [,1]
 [1,]    1
 [2,]    2

[[1]][[2]]
     [,1]
[1,]    3
[2,]    4

[[1]][[3]]
     [,1]
[1,]    5
[2,]    6


 [[2]]
 [[2]][[1]]
     [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]    2

 [[2]][[2]]
      [,1]
[1,]    3
[2,]    4

[[2]][[3]]
     [,1]
[1,]    5
[2,]    6
```

Comment: Please Clarify on which language you are discussing and also add tags to your questions.

Comment: @ZachSchulze It does have the `r` tag, and they're using R

Comment: Sorry. It is in R

Comment: Didn't even see that. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option,

```
rowMeans(do.call(cbind, lapply(lll, function(i) do.call(rbind, i))))
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Or a different presentation,

```
matrix(rowMeans(do.call(cbind, lapply(lll, function(i) 
                                   do.call(rbind, i)))), ncol = length(lll), byrow = TRUE)
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    2
#[2,]    3    4
#[3,]    5    6
```

Comment: I like second option since I need to use those in computation.

Comment: Also `rowMeans(sapply(seq_along(lll), function(i) unlist(lll[i], recursive = TRUE)))`